# correct way to deploy project in jenkins

Tags: php, git, jenkins, deployment

I have a PHP project with some unit tests.
I want to run unit tests and on success deploy my codes to my production repository.
I am using Jenkins but I don't know how can I push my codes to another repository as in jenkins I can use `git publisher`  to merge to another branch but I can't push to another repository.

I have added conditional step in build step like this:
[image of conditional build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5RdV.png) but I think this is not correct way.

Another ask is that is good way to push to another repository or shall I merge to for example production branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have added conditional step in build step like this: image of
>   conditional build but I think this is not correct way.

what you're doing is fine. i think you're worried about not using built-in jenkins git integrations. if it's as simple as adding a remote pointing at a local git repo, i don't think jenkins integrations are really helping.

> is that is good way to push to another repository or shall I merge to
>   for example production branch

it would be more conventional (and simpler, as you have found) to merge to a production branch (often called master), but lots of people also have a separate repo for production.

Comment: Thanks @burnettk, Do I need to run tests in production servers too?

Comment: and what you suggest for deploy? as I searched I see many of people are using phing

Comment: you can run tests in production servers. many people choose not to because they have test environments that mimic their production environments with sufficient fidelity. phing is a general-purpose build tool for php. if it helps you, use it, i'd say, but if your use case is simple enough (or even if it isn't), you can avoid it and just use bash. if you have follow-up questions, please submit different questions and check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.